# NSURLConnection in dispatch_queue_t

Tags: iphone, ios7, nsurlconnection

Though this question has been asked many times since the release of iOS 4.0 but I am still not able to find a solution for the NSURLConnection's delegate methods not being called in a method that is called from within a GCD queue. The code generating NSURLConnection is as below:

```
NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:nil delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
NSRunLoop* rLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[conn scheduleInRunLoop:rLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[conn start];
[rLoop run];
```

Why the application's execution stop on

```
[rLoop run];
```

making the execution of code after this line to be delayed.

Also this code works fine on iOS simulator 7.0 but not on an iOS 7 device. Can anybody explain the reason for it ?? For a background download using NSURLConnection with the received response also needs to be processed in background do I still need to schedule the NSURLConnection on mainRunLoop ?

**EDIT:**
Since the NSURLConnection is being created in a background thread which may not have its associated NSRunLoop so will below code works ?

```
[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; // This will create a runLoop if not already present for the current thread.
self.conn = [NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];// This will automatically schedule the NSURLConnection in above created runLoop and thus divert the events to get associated with delegates for NSURLConnection.
```

Comment: The first thing that stands out is `initWithRequest:nil` in your first code block. That's... unlikely to be what you want for anything at all. `NSURLConnection` is an immutable class, so it's not like you can assign this later on.

Comment: The first code snippet is dummy and not taken from actual project so in a hurry i am not able to see "nil" in initWithRequest:nil. Anyway is second code snippet ok for the issue resolving ? I mean to say if one creates a non existing run loop prior to NSURLConnection initialization then will the delegates will start getting called ? Also why is there is a difference in behavior on simulator and on iOS device ?

Comment: When you say this does not work on an iOS 7 device, what's happening? I tried it on both device and simulator, and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you show how you are dispatching the call to the queue? And some code you expect to run, say, in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`? It may be that you need to dispatch the callback code execution to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You ask "why the application's execution stop on `[rLoop run]`?" The [`run`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000321-CHDEBABE) method:

> ...runs the receiver in the `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` by repeatedly invoking `runMode:beforeDate:`. In other words, this method effectively begins an infinite loop that processes data from the run loop’s input sources and timers.

So, you'd expect to not return from `run` until the network request is done. Since you're doing this on a background thread, this behavior is generally not considered to be terribly problematic.

There are two common alternatives that bypass this problem. One is the approach of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which is to create a dedicated thread (another, besides the one used by the dispatch/operation queue). See the `AFURLConnectionOperation.m` [source code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m) for an example of that.

A lot of people will just schedule the network operation to run on the main queue, e.g.

```
[conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Two caveats about your approach:

1. If you're creating your own run loop, is often advised that you add a port to your runloop to make sure it's kept around. AFNetworking does that. So does [The truth about synchronous NSURLConnection](http://cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/).
2. Alternatively, the `run` documentation suggests that

   > Manually removing all known input sources and timers from the run loop is not a guarantee that the run loop will exit. OS X can install and remove additional input sources as needed to process requests targeted at the receiver’s thread. Those sources could therefore prevent the run loop from exiting.
   >
   > If you want the run loop to terminate, you shouldn't use this method. Instead, use one of the other run methods and also check other arbitrary conditions of your own, in a loop. A simple example would be:

   ```
   BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES;        // global
   NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
   while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
   ```

   If you're doing a `NSOperation`-based solution, for example, you'd check for `isFinished`.